# Deriving Helfrich's shape equation for closed membranes

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, reference-request

I have a bunch of papers that claim that, from the equation for shape energy:
$$ F = \frac{1}{2}k_c \int (c_1+c_2-c_0)^2 dA + \Delta p \int dV + \lambda \int dA$$
one can use "methods of variational calculus" to derive the following:
$$\Delta p - 2\lambda H + k(2H+c_0)(2H^2-2K-c_0H)+2k\nabla^2H=0$$
But I'm having a lot of trouble tracking down the original derivation. The guy who did it first was Helfrich, and here's his and Ou-yang's paper deriving it:
http://prl.aps.org/pdf/PRL/v59/i21/p2486_1 . However, they don't show an actual derivation, instead saying "the derivation will appear in a full paper by the authors" or something like that. Yet everybody cites the paper I just linked for a derivation. Does anybody know a source that can derive this, or can give me some hints to figure it out myself? To be honest I can't even figure out how to find the first variation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follow-up paper by Helfrich you are searching for is

*Bending energy of vesicle membranes: General expressions for the first, second, and third variation of the shape energy and applications to spheres and cylinders,*
Ou-Yang Zhong-can and Wolfgang Helfrich,
Physical Review A **39**, 5280-5288 (1989).

> A general equation of mechanical equilibrium of fluid membranes
>   subject to bending elasticity [reported in Phys. Rev. Lett. 59, 2486
>   (1987)] is derived in detail.